# How to listen events with Node.JS & Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am making online game server with Node.js, but I am stuck at event listening.

In table.js I wanna listen to "test" emit from client. But it looks nothing.

```
var socket = io.sockets.connected[socket_id]
socket.on("test", function (d) {
   console.log(d)
})
```

I am emit from table.js like this (it is working without problem)

```
   io.sockets.connected[socket_id].emit(event_name, data)
```

This is also result of *console.log( io.sockets.connected[socket_id] )*

```
Socket {
  nsp: 
   Namespace {
     name: '/',
     server: 
      Server {
        nsps: [Object],
        _path: '/socket.io',
        _serveClient: true,
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
        sockets: [Circular],
        eio: [Object],
        httpServer: [Object],
        engine: [Object] },
     sockets: 
      { '/#8CUB-zmn20g-hxxjAAAA': [Object],
        '/#FevFALjTPcIkP9EvAAAB': [Object],
        '/#z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD': [Circular] },
     connected: 
      { '/#8CUB-zmn20g-hxxjAAAA': [Object],
        '/#FevFALjTPcIkP9EvAAAB': [Object],
        '/#z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD': [Circular] },
     fns: [ [Function] ],
     ids: 0,
     adapter: 
      Adapter {
        nsp: [Circular],
        rooms: [Object],
        sids: [Object],
        encoder: Encoder {} },
     _events: { connection: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1 },
  server: 
   Server {
     nsps: { '/': [Object] },
     _path: '/socket.io',
     _serveClient: true,
     _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
     _origins: '*:*',
     sockets: 
      Namespace {
        name: '/',
        server: [Circular],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [Object],
        ids: 0,
        adapter: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     eio: 
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 3,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: false,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     httpServer: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 9,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::5555' },
     engine: 
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 3,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: false,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 } },
  adapter: 
   Adapter {
     nsp: 
      Namespace {
        name: '/',
        server: [Object],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [Object],
        ids: 0,
        adapter: [Circular],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     rooms: 
      { '/#8CUB-zmn20g-hxxjAAAA': [Object],
        '/#FevFALjTPcIkP9EvAAAB': [Object],
        '/#z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD': [Object] },
     sids: 
      { '/#8CUB-zmn20g-hxxjAAAA': [Object],
        '/#FevFALjTPcIkP9EvAAAB': [Object],
        '/#-VB9E9ehK70lcFOIAAAC': {},
        '/#z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD': [Object] },
     encoder: Encoder {} },
  id: '/#z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD',
  client: 
   Client {
     server: 
      Server {
        nsps: [Object],
        _path: '/socket.io',
        _serveClient: true,
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
        sockets: [Object],
        eio: [Object],
        httpServer: [Object],
        engine: [Object] },
     conn: 
      Socket {
        id: 'z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD',
        server: [Object],
        upgrading: false,
        upgraded: true,
        readyState: 'open',
        writeBuffer: [],
        packetsFn: [],
        sentCallbackFn: [Object],
        cleanupFn: [Object],
        request: [Object],
        remoteAddress: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
        checkIntervalTimer: null,
        upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
        pingTimeoutTimer: [Object],
        transport: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3 },
     encoder: Encoder {},
     decoder: Decoder { reconstructor: null, _callbacks: [Object] },
     id: 'z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD',
     request: 
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCK8z9f',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        statusMessage: null,
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: true,
        _query: [Object],
        res: [Object],
        cleanup: [Function: cleanup],
        session_id: undefined,
        read: [Function] },
     onclose: [Function: bound ],
     ondata: [Function: bound ],
     onerror: [Function: bound ],
     ondecoded: [Function: bound ],
     sockets: { '/#z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD': [Circular] },
     nsps: { '/': [Circular] },
     connectBuffer: [] },
  conn: 
   Socket {
     id: 'z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD',
     server: 
      Server {
        clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 3,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function: bound ],
        cookie: 'io',
        cookiePath: false,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        httpCompression: [Object],
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     upgrading: false,
     upgraded: true,
     readyState: 'open',
     writeBuffer: [],
     packetsFn: [],
     sentCallbackFn: [ undefined ],
     cleanupFn: [ [Function], [Function] ],
     request: 
      IncomingMessage {
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: true,
        headers: [Object],
        rawHeaders: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        rawTrailers: [],
        upgrade: false,
        url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCK8z9f',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        statusMessage: null,
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: true,
        _query: [Object],
        res: [Object],
        cleanup: [Function: cleanup],
        session_id: undefined,
        read: [Function] },
     remoteAddress: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
     checkIntervalTimer: null,
     upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
     pingTimeoutTimer: 
      { _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 85000,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 9247,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _repeat: null },
     transport: 
      WebSocket {
        readyState: 'open',
        discarded: false,
        socket: [Object],
        writable: false,
        perMessageDeflate: [Object],
        supportsBinary: true,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4 },
     _events: 
      { close: [Object],
        data: [Function: bound ],
        error: [Function: bound ] },
     _eventsCount: 3 },
  rooms: { '/#z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD': '/#z5-YdxwrsIayv7yuAAAD' },
  acks: {},
  connected: true,
  disconnected: false,
  handshake: 
   { headers: 
      { host: '127.0.0.1:5555',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36',
        accept: '*/*',
        dnt: '1',
        referer: 'http://127.0.0.1:5555/',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
        'accept-language': 'tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,bg;q=0.2,it;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2',
        cookie: 'io=-VB9E9ehK70lcFOIAAAC' },
     time: 'Wed Feb 24 2016 18:36:45 GMT+0200 (EET)',
     address: '::ffff:127.0.0.1',
     xdomain: false,
     secure: false,
     issued: 1456331805312,
     url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LCK8z9f',
     query: { EIO: '3', transport: 'polling', t: 'LCK8z9f' } },
  _events: { giris: [Function], oyna: [Function], disconnect: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 3 }
```

Please help me, thanks.

**Edit:**

First I am making table(4 people) like this.

```
new Game(io, id)
```

And my Game model.

```
function Game(io, id) {
  this.id = id
  this.io = io
  this.players = []
  this.status = 0
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Where are you listen for the incoming socket connections? Can you provide the code?

Comment: I updated bottom of question.

Comment: How do you send test events from the client?

Comment: @bolav `socket.send("test", false)` like this Bolav. There is no problem in this client.

Comment: Can it be problems with your listener? Can you try to add the listener for the `test` event after the connection. `io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('test', function(d){
    console.log('test '+d);
  });
});
`